# Select BDays from timestamp field

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to select from postgresql DB from a field which is timestamp like this `1969-11-28 00:00:00` all people which have a birthday on some date (for example 7th March).

Comment: What? you are not new here.. please update you question an expand your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_char()` to only return the month and day:

```
select *
from person
where to_char(bday, 'mm-dd') = '03-07'
```

or use the extract function:

```
select *
from person
where (extract(month from bday), extract(day from bday)) = (3,7);
```